# VMWare slow on external USB disk

Tags: usb-drive, vmware, ssd

I've recently moved my VMWare virtual machine (disk image) to an external USB SSD drive (Samsung T3). The guest operating system has became very slow to load and very unresponsive especially when launching applications.

So I've compared read speed of my external SSD to the internal SSD (where it was before and where works fine):

Internal SSD: 464 MB/s
External SSD: 357 MB/s

The internal SSD is about 25% faster than the external one, but when I run the external VM, loading times are much longer (even up to 3 times).

Is there anything I can do to make the external VM more responsive?
Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Also, the T3 comes preformatted as exFAT and it is mounted through the gnome daemon.
Could it be worth trying to reformat it as ext4 and mounting directly by command line?

Comment: Have you verified I/O latencies, too ? I would assume the USB driver could make them quite bigger.

Comment: I've just reformatted the t3 to ext4 and now the VM run just as smooth as from internal SSD. The read speed is now 366 MB/s, which is not too different from exfat, but the write speed jumped from 130MB/s to 325MB/s... I think this makes the difference. @mveroone: How do I verify the I/O latencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just reformatted the t3 to ext4 and now the VM run just as smooth as from internal SSD. The read speed is now 366 MB/s, which is not too different from exfat, but the write speed jumped from 130MB/s to 325MB/s... I think this makes the difference.